Non-Parametric Regression: Seminal Papers
This question is mostly a question for references and is not objectively answerable as recommendations for literature inherently depend on personal preference. I hope it is still ok.
I would like to ask, what you would consider seminal/important papers in non-parametric regression? The backround of the question is that I am conducting research on a specific aspect of non-parametric regression without knowing too much about it in general. Before diving in too deep into a specific direction, I would like to have some recommendations.

FYI, there is a Stack for statistics.

Thank you, I know about this stack. However, I have always felt that non-parametric regression is often investigated by mathematicians... but maybe my intuition is misled. Should there be no answers to the question on this stack, I will try to ask on the statistics one!
